# Are the affine and projective spaces $k^n$ and $P^n(k)$ , homeomorphic w.r.t. to the Zariski topology on them?

Tags: commutative-algebra, projective-space, affine-geometry, zariski-topology, affine-varieties

Are the affine and projective spaces $k^n$ and $P^n(k)$ , homeomorphic w.r.t. to the Zariski topology on them , where $k$ is an algebraically closed field ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes if $n=1$.

No if $n \ge 2$. One reason: inside $k^n$ there are two closed subsets of dimension $n-1$ with void intersection. This is not true for $P^n(k)$. ( note that the dimension of a topological space is a topological invariant).