# For which $m,n$, are the affine spaces $\mathbb A^n(k)$ and $\mathbb A^m(k)$ , with Zariski topology, are homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, commutative-algebra, affine-geometry, zariski-topology, affine-varieties

Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field. For each $n \in \mathbb N$, we can equip the affine space $\mathbb A^n(k)$ with Zariski topology. For which $m,n$, are the affine spaces $\mathbb A^n(k)$ and $\mathbb A^m(k)$ , with Zariski topology, are homeomorphic ?

Comment: Compare also with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2708319/are-the-affine-and-projective-spaces-kn-and-pnk-homeomorphic-w-r-t-to).

Comment: @Dietrich Burde : yes, but here we don't have that non-empty intersection type property ... right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximal length of a chain of closed irreducible subsets is a topological invariant. Therefore, if and only if $n=m$.

Comment: There is also [this variant](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376054/mathbb-ank-and-mathbb-ank-setminus-0-are-not-homeomorphic?rq=1), which looks much harder.

Comment: @DietrichBurde That one is beyond my knowledge (not that going beyond my knowledge is hard to begin with).

Comment: Also beyond mine. May be a good motivation for the OP.

Comment: You mean the topological dimension right ?

Comment: @misao Yes, but saying that the topological dimension is a topological invariant sounds silly.